# how to calculate a moving average in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-average

I have a dataframe column that looks like this:

```
CurrentCreditLines
0   5.0
1   14.0
2   NaN
3   5.0
4   19.0
```

with 110k records, how can I calculate the moving average? also I need it to be rounded and with type float, I tried this:

```
test["CurrentCreditLines"].rolling(min_periods=1, center=True, window=12).mean().round().float()
```

but I got the error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'float'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you that it's not an issue with your `.rolling()` method but there is no `.float()` attribute of series in pandas, so, you should use [pandas.DataFrame.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) function to manipulate column dtypes.

```
test["CurrentCreditLines"].rolling(min_periods=1, center=True, window=12).mean().round()

test["CurrentCreditLines"].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

mrVerma is completely right. As a side note, when you chain so many operations it is sometime really handy to use brackets for readability:

```py
(
    test["CurrentCreditLines"]
    .rolling(min_periods=1, center=True, window=12)
    .mean()
    .round()
    .astype(float)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, `float` is not a valid pandas method.

That said, your column looks like it is already of float type, so it is useless to perform a conversion.

Just run:

```
test["CurrentCreditLines"].rolling(min_periods=1, center=True, window=12).mean()
```

If, for some reason, the column is of another type, perform the conversion before applying the rolling mean:

```
test["CurrentCreditLines"].astype(float).rolling(min_periods=1, center=True, window=12).mean()
```